# What happens after dialing USB 3G modem

Tags: usb, modem, ppp, 3g

I have a hard time understanding how a 3G USB modem communicates with OS. As far as I understand, pretty much all USB modems work in a similar fashion - they expose USB CDC device and to connect, system sends standard AT commands to this device. Linux shouldn't need any special drivers at all and common tools should suffice. But what happens after modem is connected to the 3G network? How are IP packets sent/received?

Comment: You just get additional network device and all communications are handled by kernel. Do you really need details how kernel translates raw stream of the incoming/outgoing data into IP packets?

Comment: Well, at least a high level explanation of the process. Which process or kernel module does what and which protocols are involved. Is it similar to a dial-up process? (obviously the part after radio connection is established)